# Distinct value in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am retrieving a list of cities in Parse.

```
mMidwifeLocation = users;
String[] locations = new String[mMidwifeLocation.size()];
int i = 0;
for(ParseUser user : mMidwifeLocation) {
  locations[i] = user.getString("city");
  i++;
}
```

Within this, I want distinct values, and no null values.. Can someone give me an assist on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this should be good.
If not to long, not that inefficeint.

```
mMidwifeLocation = users;
String[] locations = new String[mMidwifeLocation.size()];
String check;
int i = 0;
for(ParseUser user : mMidwifeLocation) {
    check=user.getString("city");
    if(check!=null){
       if(!Arrays.asList(locations).contains(check)){
            locations[i] = user.getString("city");
         }
    }             
    i++;
 }
```